# r copy outside of wd based on a list

Tags: r, copy

I am trying to do a very similar thing to others but outside of the working directory which I don't want to change every time I run this particular function.

but based on a list held in a .txt file held in dir1 for example.

here's my copy function. I have read others posts but can't get them to work when there is more  than 1 .txt file in the original directory

```
#sp6
current.folder <- "test1"
new.folder6 <- "test2"

#clear file list 
list_of_files6<-NULL

# find the files that you want
list_of_files6 <- read.delim("Mp20181111.txt", header = F)

print(list_of_files6)

setwd(current.folder) 
for(i in list_of_files6)
{
  file.copy(i, new.folder6)
}
```

Comment: can you give a sample/example of `list_of_files6`?

Comment: list_of_files6 = 
SB112149.15#
SB112211.50#
SB112223.58#
SB120239.49#
SB120439.56#
SB120448.30#
SB120510.23#
SB120517.10#
SB120526.55#
SB120535.15#
SB120551.34#
No directory, maybe thats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but from what I understand you have a dataframe, list_of_files6 that contains a vector of files, and also a vector of directory names (without paths).

```
 mainDir <- as.character(getwd())
    if (nrow(list_of_files6) > 0) {
      subDir <- as.character(list_of_files6$DIRECTORYNAMES)
    } else{
      stop(NULL)
    }
    if (!(dir.exists(file.path(mainDir, subDir)))) {
      dir.create(file.path(mainDir, subDir))
    }
```

If the list_of_files6$FILENAMES doesn't have the pathway proceeding it:

```
list_of_files6$FILEPATHS <- paste0(mainDir, "/", list_of_files6$FILENAMES)
```

Assuming list_of_files6 contains directory names and file names:

```
    for(i in 1:length(list_of_files6)){
       if(file.exists(list_of_files6$FILEPATHS[i])){
        file.copy(list_of_files6$FILENAMES[i], list_of_files6$DIRECTORYNAMES[i], overwrite = TRUE)
}else{
     i <- i + 1
}
    }
```

Comment: Hey @zx8754, you answered my very first question I posted on here when I was just starting out with R and I've seen your answers a few times since. I just wanted to say thanks for answering my question as helpfully and speedily as you did, at that point I wasn't going to continue with R, but I have written almost everyday since and am now employed as a data analyst !

Answer (score 0):

I edited the above, just posting for newbies like me

```
FilesToCopy<-list.files("C:/Users/alo2/Documents_Cdrive/test1")

FilesToCopy2<-list.files(path = "C:/Users/alo2/Documents_Cdrive/test1", pattern = NULL,
           full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE,
           ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)

print(FilesToCopy2)

my_dirs <- ("C:/Users/alo2/Documents_Cdrive/test1")

FilesToCopy2<-list.files(path = "C:/Users/alo2/Documents_Cdrive/test1", pattern = NULL,
                         full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE,
                         ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)

# Your output directory to copy files to
new_dir <- "C:/Users/alo2/Documents_Cdrive/test2"
# Make sure the directory exists
dir.create(new_dir, recursive = TRUE)

# Copy the files
for(file in FilesToCopy2) {
  # See ?file.copy for more options
  file.copy(file, new_dir)
}
```